# How to place bottomAppBar in layout

Tags: java, android, material-components-android

I'm currently working on a project that uses the bottom app bar as its main navigation. but I always get an error even when I'm copy-pasting from an example source code

Here is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"></com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Here an error that I got

```
Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem last night. My problem is that I use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
```

and that version is still an alpha and not stable. So I downgraded it to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

and everything runs as smooth as butter

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-material-components-for-android-f490c4a01708) website:
Set your targetSdkVersion to the latest API version targetting Android P which is 28 and make sure your app inherits 
`Theme.MaterialComponents`
theme in order to make BottomAppBar use the latest style. Alternatively, you can declare the style for `BottomAppBar`
in widget declaration within layout xml file as follows:
`style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem recently. You need to add dependency of

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0
```

And then add `<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` to your XML layout file.

It's worked for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/vBottomBar"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/vBottomBar" android:id="@+id/vContainer">

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found the solution last night. My problem is that the current dependency version is still alpha and not stable. I was using material version '1.1.0-alpha05' so I downgraded it to 1.0.0 and everything run fine and smooth